# Событие Click не срабатывает на тачскрине

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим некий код, который при клике на выбранный оптион выполняет функцию.
На компе всё работает, на таскринах при выборе option, removeclass не срабатывает.

В чём может быть причина?

```
$('.block select option).on("click", function(){
   $('.block2').removeClass('block3');
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

На мобильных девайсах взаимодействие с select происходит через собственный UI. Вы не можете его модифицировать и вешать ивенты на option.
Используйте ивент `change` у `select`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]